# How to copy csv column into multiple fields table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `mysql` calumn that contains a long `text` string which is csv.
I want to split the csv in sql and insert it into a new table, approx 100 columns. So that each csv column turns into a table column.

Of course I could use `SUBSTRING_INDEX(csv, ';', <index>)` over and over again, but that would cause 100x splitting.

How can I split the csv column in some type of array, and use references on it eg by index?

```
INSERT INTO employees (id, name, csv) VALUES
(1, 'John Doe', 'long;csv;string;up;to;100;fields');

INSERT INTO TARGET_TABLE SELECT 
    SELECT 
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(csv, ',', 1)
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(csv, ',', 2)
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(csv, ',', ...)
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(csv, ',', 100)
    FROM employees;
```

Comment: MYSQL does not have the concept of arrays - you are going to have to do as you suggest or split in a language that does. Search for mysql split csv or mysql dlimited string.

Comment: Yea easiest approach would be to do this with a PHP script or any languages that you master